# How to display number of 10s? Keeps displaying only number of 20s

Tags: java

I have an assignment in which I have to create a method where i have to receive money from a customer and give them change back depending on the price. The frustrating situation currently is that it continues to display only the number of 20s even after I am asking for the number of tens. For example if an item cost $5 and someone gave me $155 the change would be 150. The machine should return that the change contains seven 20s and one 10. But whenever i ask for the amount of 10s, I get back 7. Can someone please help me solve this. Could you also show me a way to do the following for 5s 1s 0.75cent coins 0.35cent coins and 0.1cent coins.
The code i currently have is:

```
public class change {
    static int twentys;
    static int numtwen;
    static int tens;
    static int numten;
    static int fives;
    static int numfiv;
    static int ones;
    static int numone;
    static int scc;
    static int numscc;
    static int tcc;
    static int numtcc;
    static int occ;
    static int numocc;

    public static double result(double salesTotal, double customerPayment) {
        System.out.println("How much does it cost?");
        double price = IO.readDouble();
        salesTotal = price;
        System.out.println("How much do you have?");
        double money = IO.readDouble();
        customerPayment = money;
        double change = money - price;

        if (change > 0.34 && change / 20 >= 1) {
            numtwen = (int) change / 20;
            change = numtwen % change;
            numten = (int) change / 10;
            change = numten % change;
            numfiv = (int) change / 5;
            change = numfiv % change;
        }

        return numten;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double a = result(2, 5);
        System.out.println(numtwen);

    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(numtwen);` does print out the number of twenties, doesn't it? Just use `numten` instead?

Comment: Or you could print `a`, since it returns `numten`.

Comment: I think `numtwen%change` -- which is 7%150 in your example --
 should be `change%20`

Answer (score 0):

`change = numtwen % change;` is wrong.

`change = change % 20;` is what you want.
Similarly for the other quotients.

Beware floating-point imprecision. Currency is not well represented by floating-point values in programming.